# How to configure and view logging using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, logging

I am porting my C# .Net Core 3.1 application from log4net to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. Updating the code went surprisingly smoothly, and so I am able to build and run the app as before. However, I cannot work out how to see any logging output at all! I have Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.1.3 as a package dependency.

For example, I can run the app from the console using dotnet run but cannot get any logging to show up in the console. I have tried a lot of code along these lines:

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder
    .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Debug)
    .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Debug)
    .AddFilter("Namespace.Class", LogLevel.Debug)
    .AddConsole()
);
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Namespace.Class");
logger.LogError("This is an error message.");
logger.LogInformation("This is an information message.");
logger.LogDebug("This is a debug message.");
```

However, I don't see any logging output in the console. I would also like to send logging to a file, but cannot work out how to do this either. Any guidance that gets me started would be welcome.

Comment: Does removing the filters change the behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

In the tradition of answering my own questions, in the hopes that it will help other people with the same problem, I worked this out.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 and my application is set to be a Windows Application. This means that Console output does not go directly to what I think of as the Console! I changed the projects's Output Type to Console Application, and now I do see the logging output through Visual Studio's Debug window, and if I run the application using dotnet run